# How to add support for more than 4 chip-select to Beaglebone's SPI interface

Tags: linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, spi

Beaglebone's SPI1 interface has 2 native CS. I want to add 4 more GPIO CS to SPI1. Total 6 CS.
I added all 6 CS entries to the device tree's `cs-gpios` as shown below.

```
cs-gpios = <0>, 
           <0>, 
           <&gpio3 19 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>, 
           <&gpio1 18 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>, 
           <&gpio1 16 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>, 
           <&gpio1 17 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
```

While testing I observed that only devices connected to the first 4 CS works well. The transaction with the last 2 devices throws a timeout error (timeout error verified from dmesg).

After looking at am33xx.dtsi and spi-omap2-mcspi.c driver file, it seems like the SPI driver support only 4 CS.

How do I extend the SPI driver to support 6 CS?

Basically, I am trying to interface 6 mcp4921 devices via SPI1.

Using kernel version 4.14.108-ti-r134.

**References**
Beaglebone's version.sh output [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vsthV7MMP8)
[spi-omap2-mcspi driver](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.14/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c)
[mcp4922 driver](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.14/drivers/iio/dac/mcp4922.c)
[omap2 dtsi](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.14/arch/arm/boot/dts/omap2.dtsi)
[omap4 dtsi](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.14/arch/arm/boot/dts/omap4.dtsi)

Comment: You missed to tell the kernel version along with a link to the driver (who knows what you meant under BB).

Comment: Edited. Please re-check the question area.

Comment: According to the current driver version https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c#L1429 it supports as many GPIO chipselects as possible (I guess less than 32, though). So, I would recommend to test on vanilla v5.12.y first and see if you can use it. Then try to figure out what's wrong with your quite old kernel.

Comment: Sure I will give it a try. But I don't think it will work though. Because number of chip-select depends on value set by `ti,spi-num-cs` property https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c#L1441 .
And this property is set in a top-level device tree file (example, am33xx.dtsi).

Comment: When GPIO descriptors are in use (see `use_gpio_descritors` (which is exact line I pointed out by the link), it relies on **cs** array of GPIOs. The custom property is not used in that case I think.

Comment: It appears that the upstream driver had a limitation of 3 CS. See https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/broonie/spi.git/commit/?h=for-5.13&id=13817d466eb8713a1ffd254f537402f091d48444 and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/broonie/spi.git/commit/?h=for-5.14&id=ec679bda639fe84b78d473526ae27c74dea383fb for the details.